# The file upload code is not working

Tags: php, mysql

here is my front end script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>NEW PRODUCT PAGE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="adminstyle.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--  Begin

function resetform()
{
document.forms[0].elements[1]=="";
    }

function submitForms()
{
if (isName() && isPath() && isCategory() && isPrice() && isDesc() && isType() && isViews())
    if (confirm("\n You are about to submit this form. \n\nPress Ok to submit. Cancel to abort."))
{
alert("Your form has been sent successfully.");
return true;
}
else
{
alert("You have chosen to abort the registration.");
return false;
}
else 
return false;
}


function acceptw()
{
if(event.keyCode>45 && event.keyCode<57)
{
event.returnValue=false
window.alert("Sorry ! You can only enter Words.")
}
else
{
if(event.which>45 && event.which<57)
{
event.returnValue=false
window.alert("Sorry ! You can only enter Words.")
}
}
}


function isName()
{
if (document.forms[0].elements[0].value == "")
{
alert ("The Name field is blank. Please enter your Name.")
document.forms[0].elements[0].focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}


function isPath()
{
if (document.forms[0].elements[1].value == "")
{
alert ("The Path field is blank. \n\nPlease enter Path.")
document.forms[0].elements[1].focus();
    return false;
}
return true;
}


function isCategory()
{
if (document.forms[0].elements[2].value == "")
{
alert ("The Category field is blank. \n\nPlease enter Category.")
document.forms[0].elements[2].focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}


    function isPrice()
{
if (document.forms[0].elements[3].value == "")
{
alert ("The Price field is blank. \n\nPlease enter Price.")
document.forms[0].elements[3].focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}


function isDesc()
{
if (document.forms[0].elements[4].value == "")
{
alert ("The Description field is blank. \n\nPlease enter Description")
document.forms[0].elements[4].focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}

function isType()
{
if (document.forms[0].elements[5].value == "")
{
alert ("The Type field is blank. Please enter Type.")
document.forms[0].elements[5].focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}


function isViews()
{
if (document.forms[0].elements[6].value == "")
{
alert ("The Views field is blank. Please enter Views.")
document.forms[0].elements[6].focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}



function writeName()
{
alert('test');

document.getElementById('Name').value =     document.getElementById('file').value;
}

// End -->
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <?php

// User is already logged in. Redirect them somewhere useful.
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
echo "<script>alert('Web Master Says : : Login First :-( !!!')</script>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;url=../index.php'>";
exit();
}

else if(!isset($_SESSION['status']) )
{
echo "<script>alert('INTRUDER!!!: :')</script>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;url=../index.php'>";
exit();
}

else
{
$admin = $_SESSION['username'];
}

?>

<p align="center"><b>NEW PRODUCT PAGE</b></p>

<?php echo 'Hi, <strong>' . $admin . '</strong> Good To See You Working! || <a href="logout.php"> Logout </a>'; ?>

<br />
<div align="center">
<?php include("adminmenu.php");?>
</div>

<br />

<div align="center">
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5" height="96">
    <form name="formRegister" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"     action="confirmprod.php" onSubmit="return submitForms()">
    <table width="400" align="center" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td bgColor="c6d3ce">
          <table width="400" border="0">
            <tr bgColor="dee7e7">
              <td width="165">Name</td>
              <td><b><input type="text" id="Name" size="25" name="Name"></b>    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgColor="e7efef">
              <td>Path</td>
              <td><b><input type="file" size="25" name="Path"></b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgColor="e7efef">
              <td>Category</td>
              <td><b><input type="text" size="20" name="Category" onKeypress="if (event.keyCode < 45 || event.keyCode > 57) event.returnValue = false;"></b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgColor="e7efef">
              <td>Price</td>
              <td><b><input type="text" maxlength="10" name="Price" size="20" onKeypress="if (event.keyCode < 45 || event.keyCode > 57) event.returnValue = false;"></b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgColor="e7efef">
              <td>Description</td>
              <td><b><textarea cols="20" rows="2" name="Desc"></textarea></b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgColor="e7efef">
              <td>Type</td>
              <td><b><input type="text" size="20" name="Type"></b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgColor="dee7e7">
              <td>Views</td>
              <td><b><input type="text" maxlength="10" name="Views" onKeypress="if (event.keyCode < 45 || event.keyCode > 57) event.returnValue = false;"></b></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table width="400" align="center" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" width="200"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        <td align="center" width="200"><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset Form" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to reset the current information?');"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my backend code

```
<?php
session_start();
include("includes/mysqli_connection.php");

// User is already logged in. Redirect them somewhere useful.
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
echo "<script>alert('Web Master Says : : Login First :-( !!!')</script>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;url=../index.php'>";
exit();
}

else if(!isset($_SESSION['status']) )
{
echo "<script>alert('INTRUDER!!!: :')</script>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;url=../index.php'>";
exit();
}

else
{
$admin = $_SESSION['username'];
}

?>

<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']));
$Name =  mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,htmlspecialchars($_POST['Name']));
$Path = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,htmlspecialchars($_POST['Path']));
$Category = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,htmlspecialchars($_POST['Category']));
$Price = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,htmlspecialchars($_POST['Price']));
$Descr = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,htmlspecialchars($_POST['Descr']));
$Type = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,htmlspecialchars($_POST['Type']));
$Views =  mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,htmlspecialchars($_POST['Views']));
}

else
{
 echo "ERROR!!!";
 $id = "";
}

$updateuser = "UPDATE jewellery SET prodname='$Name', path='$Path',  category='$Category', price='$Price', descr='$Descr', type='$Type',  noviews='$Views' WHERE id='$id'";

$query = mysqli_query($db_conx,$updateuser);

if($query)
{
    echo "<script>alert('Successfully Updated!')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location.href='viewprod.php';</script>";
}

else
{
    echo "Could not update data";
    echo "<script>window.location.href='viewprod.php';</script>";
}
?>
```

the major issue its about uploading file to a folder and saving path in database where in this script i am able to save the path but cannot able to upload file can anyone please help me how to solve it

Comment: show us the code you used for uploading files !

Comment: dude, replace `$_POST['Path'];` to `$_FILES['Path']['tmp_name']`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 // Included configuration file in our code.

include ("includes/mysqli_connection.php");

$prodname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['Name']);
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['Category']);
$price = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['Price']);
$desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['Desc']);
$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['Type']);
$views = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['Views']);
$view_target_path='';
 function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
     {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
       switch($imagetype)
       {
           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
           case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';
           default: return false;
       }
     }
if (!empty($_FILES["Path"]["name"])) {

    $file_name=$_FILES["Path"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["Path"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["Path"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".$price.time().$ext;
        $view_target_path="Photos/moses/".$imagename;
        $target_path="../Photos/moses/".$imagename;
 if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {
       // $name=$_REQUEST['name'];

//      mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ---->  ".mysql_error()); 
//            echo 'done';

    }else{

     exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
 }

    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM jewellery WHERE prodname = '$prodname'";

  $result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

if(!mysqli_num_rows($result))
{   
    $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO jewellery (prodname, path, category, price, descr, type, noviews)
            VALUES ('$prodname', '$view_target_path', '$category', '$price', '$desc', '$type', '$views')";

    mysqli_query($db_conx, $insertSQL);

    if($insertSQL)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Successfully Added!')</script>";

        echo "<script>window.location.href='viewprod.php'</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'An error occured while uploading the entry to database. Please try again later.';
    }
}

else
{
    echo "<font color='red'>Sorry This Product already exists!</font>";
    echo "<script>alert('Redirecting...')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location.href='newprod.php'</script>";
}

// Close your database connection
mysqli_close($db_conx);
?>
```